# How to make video streaming with createTemporaryDirectLink faster with Dropbox PHP Core SDK

Tags: php, api, dropbox

Right now, I am using `createTemporaryDirectLink` with **Dropbox PHP Core SDK**

The code looks like this:

```
list($url, $expires) = $client->createTemporaryDirectLink("/".$destination);
header("location: $url");
```

The problem: Buffering is frequent, which makes the experience unpleasant. **The problem is not with my wifi connection, I checked YouTube and the experience was 10 times better...**

Can you purchase a faster api key with Dropbox? Or, do anything with code to make the experience faster...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check that there isn't anything on your network connection that may be interfering with or throttling your connection to Dropbox (e.g., firewall, security software, ISP, etc.)

Unfortunately, beyond that, there isn't much you can do to impact this. Dropbox does not offer faster speeds for different keys, plans, etc.

Note that all of the Dropbox servers are located in the US. Your connection speed to Dropbox depends on the routing you get between your ISP and the Dropbox servers, and may be slower than your ISP's rated speeds.

Sometimes resetting or retrying your connection gets you a different route and better speeds, but that is outside of Dropbox's control. Some ISPs also throttle sustained connections so if you see an initial high connection speed followed by lower speeds, that could be the reason.

Also, YouTube may not be a good comparison, as the video player can automatically adjust the quality (and thereby transfer size) of the video based on the available bandwidth. The URL returned by `createTemporaryDirectLink`, on the other hand, is always the full/original content stored in the file. If it's a high resolution/bitrate, it can't automatically lower that to accommodate for the available network connection.